# How to stop OS X from system sleep when the Display sleeps?

Tags: sleep-wake, virtualbox, power-management, energy

On OS X Yosemite I found that all operations interupt once I switch of the monitor for a while. Most notabaly copy processes of large files, simply pause. Every time OS X puts the Display to sleep (or if I switch it of manually as well!), VirtualBox virtual machines also will be put to sleep.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can we assume your Mac is set to never sleep? Can we also assume that you want your display to sleep but the VM to run during the time between when the display blanks and the machine sleeps?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Currently I have also set the displays to never sleep and then the VMs stay operational. As soon as I put the displays to sleep (e.g. through hot corners) then the VM will sleep as well and stop for example indexing files.

Comment: The option "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off" is also checked inside System Settings Energy Saver.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?